# How to insert list of objects to GoJs?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, gojs

I have  sent a list of objects to a jsp page(containing GoJs library) from a java controller class .I want to add the details in these list to GoJs.And also i want to display all the details of it in a single page?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include any specifics in your question, so I can only give you general answers.

If the page is receiving data from the server, typically in a successful response to a call to XMLHttpRequest, you could call [**Model.addNodeDataCollection**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#addNodeDataCollection) and [**GraphLinksModel.addLinkDataCollection**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#addLinkDataCollection).

You might want to read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/usingModels.html#ModifyingModels for more discussion.

If you want to show details of a selected object, you can implement some HTML that shows those details.  Typically one establishes a "ChangedSelection" [**DiagramEvent**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DiagramEvent.html) listener on the [**Diagram**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html).

Read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/events.html for more discussion.